# nohup won't finish my MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, ssh, nohup

I have a Matlab script that I run with nohup when I ssh to a server. For some reason, it looks like the programs runs "flawlessly" but when I check the output file it's blank, and none of the files it was supposed to generate are created. So it seems as if MATLAB goes inside the function that I want to run, and then quits sporadically. Yet it quits with a [+DONE] flag which is very strange, since it really isn't done, if anything, I don't think it actually started...

I don't get the same problem if I open up MATLAB and run the same function on the GUI while I'm ssh'ed.

This is what I put in the terminal:

```
nohup matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash <function_CV.m >CV_file.txt </dev/null &
```

I added the "< /dev/null"
because my nohup was getting weird with a looped 'Bad file descriptor error' for a pointless instruction such as magic(3);exit;. So I'm not sure if maybe my nohup version is buggy?

Update: I've decided to use screen instead. I'd still appreciate any workarounds to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is very strange. The only solution I could came up with would be to replace:

```
nohup matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash <function_CV.m >CV_file.txt </dev/null &
```

with:

```
nohup matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash function_CV.M > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > CV_file.txt
```

I tried it with some own .m file and it worked, so either it should work for you, either the problem is in your function_CV.m.

Hope this helps!